# How to get list of prospects using email ids

Tags: rest-api, pardot

I am new to pardot. We are trying to push data in pardot[email id, first name and last name]. So basically we are checking if the email id is already registered in pardot or already registered in prospect record.if yes in that case we are just adding the record in list otherwise we are creating a new prospect and adding in list.
I have checked pardot salesforce official document for bulk query using email ids but unfortunately i am unable to find bulk api to get records using email ids.

[query api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/bulk-actions-v5.html#query)

is there any way to filter the prospects using email ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can issue the V5 Prospect Query API with a single Email Address.  Though with this approach, you may as well use the V5 Prospect Upsert matching by email.

I know you are looking for a Bulk option, sadly there really isn't one.

I would recommend you consider storing the Pardot Prospect Id in your external system, so that in the future you can take advantage of V3/4 Bulk Insert & Bulk Update